# How to Show div when a Radio Button is Clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two radios buttons but I want one to show another div if the user clicks yes. I'm new in React.
I have tried this code but the second does not hide the content of the first.

Break down
The user clicks yes,
Another div opens for more info.
The user clicks no,
The div that opened earlier closed. 
I know how to toggle in JavaScript but I want to update based on the state.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    class Radio extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { clickedYes: false, clickedNo: false };
        this.yesHandler = this.yesHandler.bind(this);
        this.noHandler = this.noHandler.bind(this);
      }
      yesHandler() {
        this.setState({
          clickedYes: !this.state.clickedYes
        });
      }
      noHandler() {
        this.setState({
          clickedNo: !this.state.clickedNo
        });
      }
      render() {
        const radioNo = this.state.clickedNo ?
        //  Hide div when true 
         : null;

        const radioYes = this.state.clickedYes ? <h1>Yes</h1> : null;

        return (
          <>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="release"
              id=""
              clickedYes={this.state.clickedYes}
              onClick={this.yesHandler}
             />
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="release"
              clickedNo={this.state.clickedNo}
              onClick={this.noHandler}
              id=""
            />

            {radioYes}
            {radioNo}
          </>
        );
       }
     }
     export default Radio;
```

Comment: You can try with ```{this.state.clickedYes && (<div>Yes</div>)}
            {this.state.clickedNo && (<div>No</div>)}```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here are two solutions.**

#### With *standard* React

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Radio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { status: 0 }; // 0: no show, 1: show yes, 2: show no.
  }

  radioHandler = (status) => {
    this.setState({ status });
  };

  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <input type="radio" name="release" checked={status === 1} onClick={(e) => this.radioHandler(1)} />
        <input type="radio" name="release" checked={status === 2} onClick={(e) => this.radioHandler(2)} />
        {status === 1 && drawYesContent()}
        {status === 2 && drawNoContent()}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Radio;
```

#### With React Hook

```
import React from "react";

function Radio () {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(0) // 0: no show, 1: show yes, 2: show no.

  const radioHandler = (status) => {
    setStatus(status);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="radio" name="release" checked={status === 1} onClick={(e) => radioHandler(1)} />
      <input type="radio" name="release" checked={status === 2} onClick={(e) => radioHandler(2)} />
      {status === 1 && drawYesContent()}
      {status === 2 && drawNoContent()}
    </>
  );
}

export default Radio;
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How to do this with hooks?

Comment: @TarasH the useState and setStatus are the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

@bgaynor78 is right, but I would prefer something like the following, because you will not create an *invisible* dom node

```
{
  this.state.clickedYes && (<div>This shows when the radioYes input is clicked</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply add a `style` declaration to your div you want to show, then just hook that up to your state object.

```
  <div style={{ display: this.state.clickedYes ? 'block' : 'none'}}>This shows when the radioYes input is clicked</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your method works but I don't want to go with styling method.